# Log in using Twitter

Tags: feature-request, login

I wonder why Stack Overflow doesn't allow a user to sign in with Twitter. Could there be any technical reason or is social login with Twitter not so popular/useful?

Answer (score 5):

The short version is "Every provider we support adds a ton of overhead in both implementation and support."

There are a couple other considerations (we don't require an email, but it's a nice to have - especially for account recovery, for example), but having said that, the last time we looked at what it'd take to support Twitter-based authentication was a couple years back. Things have probably changed some since then, so it might be worth revisiting, but if I'm honest, it'd take a *very* popular request at this point.

FWIW, my personal preference, as someone who has done extensive work on our auth and recovery code, would be to reduce the number of credential providers we support rather than add another one at this point.

Comment: You would expect that OAuth is a standard that makes it easy to have or add multiple identity providers. Is that standard maybe broken by design?

Comment: @rene - some important items in the standard end up being implemented differently by different providers (either due to misunderstanding the spec or it being open to interpretations). This makes it difficult to support in a robust manner that will work everywhere.